# How to use MS Stochastic Indicator

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart, stochastic

I am working on drawing a stochastic indicator, using double arrays containing open high low close data, adjusted to time periods of 5,10,15 and 30 minutes.

```
chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.StochasticIndicator, 
"21,3",
"highPriceArray:Y,lowPriceArray:Y2,closePriceArray:Y4"
, "percentage_K_values:Y,percentage_D_values:Y");
```

The function above is the one I'm using from the MSDN library,

- How can I convert my double arrays of OHLC values to a time series format so I can, input them to this function and obtain %K and %D values afterward in return, and proceed to plot the chart?

  ```
              openPriceArray[ii] = obj[0];
              highPriceArray[ii] = obj[1];
              lowPriceArray[ii] = obj[2];
              closePriceArray[ii] = obj[3];
  ```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you need any actual *time* value, like `DateTime`. From what I found here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456620.aspx), they just use integers for days. How is your data divided in time? If it's in blocks of 5 minutes, perhaps 1, 2, 3 and 6 are the values you need for 5, 10, 15 and 30 minutes (just a wild guess).

Comment: i have the time value and i have the value of the stock at that point. basically i have all the data needed to construct a stochastic by hand.

but C# has a stochastic function which requires me to pass the data as a time series .

chart.Series["open"].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now,lowPriceArray[i]);

i can loop and create a chart with series plotted on it ,i am not sure how to integrate the output from the stochastic function mentioned above to this. basically i want to convert ARRAYS [datetime,price] to time series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sample code, with comments, should get you going. You can also refer to the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456620.aspx).

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load your data into a List<DataPoint>
    List<DataPoint> data = GetData();

    /*
     * dp.XValue - DateTime
     * dp.YValues[0] - High
     * dp.YValues[1] - Low
     * dp.YValues[2] - Open
     * dp.YValues[3] - Close
     */

    foreach (DataPoint dp in data)
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = chart1.Series[0].Points.Max(p => p.YValues[0]);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points.Min(p => p.YValues[1]);

    chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.StochasticIndicator,
    "10,10",
    "HLOC-Price:Y,HLOC-Price:Y2,HLOC-Price:Y4",
    "K-Indicator,D-Indicator");

    /*
     * HLOC-Price - Candlestick Series[0], primary Y-axis
     * K-Indicator - Line Series[1], secondary Y-axis
     * D-Indicator - Line Series[2], secondary Y-axis
     */
}
```